# Spring boot initializing bean at startup with constructor parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to initialize the following `PointQuadTree` class on startup using Spring Boot with constructor parameters, and make the object available throughout the application.  The constructor parameters 'minX, maxX, ...' need to come from the application.properties file.

*PointQuadTree*

```
public class PointQuadTree<T extends PointQuadTree.Item> {

   private final Bounds mBounds;

   public PointQuadTree(double minX, double maxX, double minY, double maxY) {
      this(new Bounds(minX, maxX, minY, maxY));
   }

   ...

}
```

*Bounds*

```
public class Bounds {
   public final double minX;
   public final double minY;

   public final double maxX;
   public final double maxY;

   public final double midX;
   public final double midY;

   public Bounds(double minX, double maxX, double minY, double maxY) {
      this.minX = minX;
      this.minY = minY;
      this.maxX = maxX;
      this.maxY = maxY;

      midX = (minX + maxX) / 2;
      midY = (minY + maxY) / 2;
   }

   ...
}
```

I've tried annotating `PointQuadTree` with `@Component`, but there is not constructor without parameters.  Even if I add a constructor without parameters `Bounds` is `final`, so it cannot be set after `PointQuadTree` is initialized. Also `Bounds` has a constructor with parameters only.

After `PointQuadTree` is initialized, I need it to sit in memory and need to be able to autowire it in other components to read/remove/add items.  I have no idea how to do this with Spring Boot.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but use JavaConfig to construct the beans and an `@ConfigurationProperties` for the values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is as simple as creating beans in Spring way...

```
@Configuration
public class AppBeans{
@Value("${minx:100}")
private double minX;
...so on ..
 @Bean
   public PointQuadTree pointQuadTree()
   {
      return new PointQuadTree(minX...so on);
   }

}
```

and inject this bean where you want using `@Autowired`

Here `${minx:100}`, tries to read from properties file, if not specified takes the default as `100`

Comment: The bean seems to be initialising now, but when I autowire it in e.g. class `A` and `B`, it seems to be a different object in both classes.  If I add items to a `java.util.List` which is in `PointQuadTree` in class `A`, those items are not in class `B`.  Are they in a different context or something like that?

Comment: I am sorry..didn't get the exact query..can you update your question what exactly you are looking for? as far as context concern no its not

Comment: It's working now.  I've put a `@Bean(name = "pointQuadTree")` annotation on the bean, and then on the autowired object I've also added `@Qualifier("pointQuadTree")`.

Comment: This is the perfect solution. I created a similar for db connection to create once and be available for all the Beans.

Answer (score 1):

in some configuration file create a spring bean of tree, something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class PointQuadTreeBeans
{

   @Bean(name="theSameTree")
   public PointQuadTree getPointQuadTree(Environment env)
   {
      double minX = env.getProperty("minX");
      double maxX = env.getProperty("maxX");
      double minY = env.getProperty("minY");
      double maxY = env.getProperty("maxY");
      PointQuadTree tree = new PointQuadTree(minX, maxX, minY, maxY);
   }


}
```

and add this class to spring componentScan

**UPD**

another way:

instead of `double minX = env.getProperty("minX");` you can create fields with `@Value`, like @chrylis said in comment:

```
@Value("${minX}")
private double minX;
```

then use it field to create bean.

Comment: Spring has cleaner support for property injection, with either `@ConfigurationProperties` or `@Value`.